# Azure Windows Server 2016 Auto expand disk?

Tags: azure

I want to deploy a Windows server 2016 VM in Azure.
As far as I am aware, Azure VM's are deployed with an "OS" disk, as well as a regular disk. The OS disk is tiny: 30GB.

I was unfortunate enough to waste about 30h of my life trying to figure out why my Postgresql DB was saying the disk is full while I was going on a disk-expanding rampage via the Azure portal, only to find out that I was expanding the regular disk, and not the OS disk...

Anyway, I now want to deploy my Postgresql DB to the regular disk (once I figure out how), but I have another problem:

My DB is likely to get very large, and continue to grow. How can I set my instance to automatically expand the disk Postgresql is installed on?

I have been through the MS "documentation", but I really cannot make heads from tails of it.

Thanks!

Comment: This might be able to be something you can do programatically via APIs. You would have to expand the storage in Azure and the disk in Windows. Due to the nature of the request, I doubt there is an automatic way to do this. Just make a disk large enough to support your database for a long period of time and monitor it. Storage is cheap.

Comment: FYI you can deploy Azure VMs with larger size "OS disks"

Answer (score 1):

Basically, there are two abstractions you can play with.  The first is Azure Disks (which have preset sizes and a preset number you can add per VM type) and the second is storage spaces/storage direct inside windows server 2016.  The process would look something like this

1. Create an appropriate storage pool with the initial set of disks (setup for striping)
2. Set an Azure Alert on disk space to inform you of when you are reaching a critical point
3. Add a disk via the Azure portal (it will then show up in the disk manager)
4. Add the disk to the existing storage pool
5. Follow: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-spaces/resize-volumes

Of course steps 3-5 could be automated with an Azure Automation Runbook (Azure alerts can be configured to kick these off automatically).

Answer (score 0):

Based on my knowledge, Linux VM OS disk is 30GB and Windows VM OS disk is 128GB.

If you want to increase your OS disk, you need to stop your VM firstly. So, I don't suggest you do it  automatically.

It is easy for you to increase your OS disk on Azure Portal, please refer to my [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1221648/increasing-c-size-of-a-vm-in-azure/1221655#1221655). Note: It works on managed disk and unmanaged disk. Also, it works on Linux VM and Windows VM.